Connecting Palantir to Salesforce - how do you access the data tables (the SObjects)?
We’ve followed these Palantir documented connector steps:
https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/available-connectors/salesforce/
and have established a connection with the Salesforce Connected App, but in the preview do not see any of the Salesforce data tables (SObjects) that contain the data we want to access.
We only see this:

whereas the Palantir documentation says:

The connector models all available standard and custom Salesforce
objects as Foundry datasets. Schemas are retrieved dynamically. The
exploration view allows you to browse the data model and preview how
Salesforce objects would appear once imported to Foundry.

and this:

The connector leverages the Salesforce SOAP API that is subject to the
Salesforce SOAP API Call Limits.

What are we missing?
(Yes this is likely only answerable by someone using both products. Also asked on https://stackoverflow.com/ and https://community.palantir.com/).
PS
In the Palantir logs there are multiple of these errors that appear to be blocking the process of finding out about the Salesforce tables:

Error: Invalid HTTP response! System error: UnknownHostException -
xxxxxxxx-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com.

Not clear to me if these originate from Palantir or from Salesforce. I've added an Egress Policy to match at the Palantir side and have added the Palantir IP addresses as Trusted IP Ranges in Network Access in Setup.
PPS
The connection appears established as the "Connected Apps OAuth Usage" at the Salesforce side is incrementing.

are you sure the user you are using for connecting to Salesforce has enough permissions? The Connected App simply allows a 3rd party system to establish connection with Salesforce. Top of my head you generally need API permission. Then to have access to SObjects you need your user to have permission to access those SObjects (either by Profile or Permission Set). So you might want to ask the Salesforce System Admin if your user definitely has permission on Salesforce objects. Though it's rare not to see anything and I would have thought you should still see some information like core objects Ac

Thanks. I've double checked that the user is an SA and so should have access. And the Connected App looks good too. So stuck still.

That looks like Palantir is unable to resolve the IP address for the dev org. Is it worth trying with login.salesforce.com or a trial org? Can you see the login attempts at Salesforce by any chance?

Hi @JefersonChaves, The connection appears to be established as the "Connected App User's Usage" does go up; this failure seems to come later. But yes trying a different org is a good next step. Also have a support request in to Palantir but not sure how long that will take.

Found my problem. As is usually the case, it was my mistake setting up the connection.
The Palantir documentations says:
Select api, offline_access, and refresh_token from the available OAuth Scopes.

for the Salesforce Connected App and I'd selected the wrong "api" one in the "Selected OAuth Scopes". The correct ones are:

Manage user data via APIs (api)
Perform requests at any time (refresh_token, offline_access)

per this screen shot:

With these set correctly, I see all the Salesforce tables listed in a new section of the "Preview source" and the downstream logic works:

